# Etag and LastModifiedDate donot change after file editing

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

After editing a document in GoogleDrive, it seems that the LastModified value doesn't change immediately sometimes.  It looks like the value will be updated in a few minutes.

I tried to fetch the Etag of the document by DriveSDK, it also happens to the Etag value.

This strange behavior stops me getting the document status (modified or not) at real time.  Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

[Sample Request and Response]
The request is just GoogleDrive ListFiles : https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files

Here's the part of the response JSON, and you can see that the ModifiedDate is earlier than ModifiedByMeDate.

```
 {
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
 "etag": "\"3NNCnvnQuji-pODa6SMQ6atlc3M/oKnf21kAcJKTCIycS597xCSR2bk\"",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#file",
   "id": "1lZjcJIf3Chuu5upFqtiqfTRnRw7*****rFL_tlO8A",
   "etag": "\"3NNCnvnQuji-pODa6SMQ6atlc3M/MTM1NDY5MzMyMzQ1Mg\"",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1lZjcJIf3Chuu5upFqtiqfTRnRw7wSUjbRurFL_tlO8A",
   "alternateLink": "https://docs.google.com/a/*****.com/document/d/1lZjcJIf3Chuu5upFqtiqfTRnRw7wSUjbRurFL_tlO8A/edit",
   "embedLink": "https://docs.google.com/a/*****.com/document/d/1lZjcJIf3Chuu5upFqtiqfTRnRw7wSUjbRurFL_tlO8A/preview",
   "iconLink": "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_11_document_list.png",
   "thumbnailLink": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/vt?gd=true&id=1lZjcJIf3Chuu5upFqtiq*****7wSUjbRurFL_tlO8A&v=22&s=AMedNnoAAAAAU*****UK74n3UiIg0L4TY-NwP3EaAU&sz=s220",
   "title": "TestFile",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
   "labels": {
    "starred": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "trashed": false,
    "restricted": false,
    "viewed": true
   },
   "createdDate": "2012-07-24T08:14:13.918Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2012-12-06T01:49:57.982Z",
   "modifiedByMeDate": "2012-12-06T01:49:57.982Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2012-12-06T01:50:06.974Z",
   "parents": [
    {
     "kind": "drive#parentReference",
     "id": "0AJ-aGTt-gWksUk9PVA",
     "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1lZjcJIf3Chuu5upFqtiqfTRnRw7wSUjbRurFL_tlO8A/parents/0AJ-aGTt-gWksUk9PVA",
     "parentLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0AJ-aGTt-gWksUk9PVA",
     "isRoot": true
    }
   ],
   "exportLinks": {
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=1l*****huu5upFqtiqfTRnRw7wSUjbRurFL_tlO8A&exportFormat=docx",
    "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=1lZjcJIf3Chuu5upF*****SUjbRurFL_tlO8A&exportFormat=odt",
    "text/html": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=1lZjcJIf3Chuu5upFqtiqfTRnRw7wSUj*****L_tlO8A&exportFormat=html",
    "application/rtf": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=1lZjcJIf3Chuu5upFqtiq*****SUjbRurFL_tlO8A&exportFormat=rtf",
    "text/plain": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=1lZjcJIf3Chuu5upFqtiqf*****SUjbRurFL_tlO8A&exportFormat=txt",
    "application/pdf": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=1lZjcJIf3C*****fTRnRw7wSUjbRurFL_tlO8A&exportFormat=pdf"
   },
   "userPermission": {
    "kind": "drive#permission",
    "etag": "\"3NNCnvnQuji-pODa6SMQ6atlc3M/6LfqbkrWujmUe1WSDkyhTxdIUCc\"",
    "id": "me",
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1lZjcJIf3Chuu5upFqtiqfTRnRw7wSUjbRurFL_tlO8A/permissions/me",
    "role": "owner",
    "type": "user"
   },
   "quotaBytesUsed": "0",
   "ownerNames": [
    "***** *****"
   ],
   "lastModifyingUserName": "***** *****",
   "editable": true,
   "writersCanShare": true,
   "appDataContents": false
  },
```

Comment: Please add a sample request with the corresponding JSON response showing that the lastModified value hasn't changed.

Comment: Hi Claudio, I've just attached the sample response JSON.

Comment: If you want to set the modifiedDate field when sending an update request, you also have to set setModifiedDate=true in your request parameters: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update

Comment: @ClaudioCherubino: what about the ETag value of a document, is it updated asynchronously as http://stackoverflow.com/a/13738347/1097104 suggests? If it is, then how can I reliably detect that a document has been modified by somebody else?

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't answer the question but I would just like to comment on what `etag` and `modifiedDate` means on `File` resources. `File` `etag` seems to just directly correspond to the `modifiedDate` value. The second part of the `etag` (after the slash) is just an encoding of the `modifiedDate`.

In the Documents List API, there's a property called `app:edited` besides the `updated` property (which seems to correspond to `modifiedDate` here). The way these timestamps change are not clearly documented, but I've noticed that `app:edited` changes on virtually every change (e.g. starring of a file, even by another user if I remember correctly) and `updated` changes are more limited (e.g. for content modifications and permission changes). And the `etag` before directly corresponds to `app:edited`, which is good because a change of `app:edited` indicates that there was really a change (sometimes it changes too much though, like starring of a file by a different user, as it doesn't really affect the current user's metadata).

What I want to say is that I think Documents List's `etag` (and having the `app:edited` property) is better than the Drive API having `modifiedDate` only. The problem with the latter is that you don't have a reliable way to determine if a `File` resource has changed or not. For example, if you just like to check if a `File` resource has changed, you could've used the files.get method with an `If-None-Match` header using the `etag`. But `etag` doesn't always change because `modifiedDate` doesn't always change. It changes, for example, when there's new content, or changed ACL, or changed description, but does not change, for example, when trashed, or parents changed. When comparing two resources, you can't reliably determine which one is newer. Add the fact that `modifiedDate` can be set (e.g. it would be possible to set the `modifiedDate` to an earlier value, or even a constant value, and the `etag` with it). The intended purpose of `etag` is lost. There are many cases where we can't just rely on the changes list, and if `etag` behaves properly, it would be huge help for determining the changes that happened.

What I suggest is to restore the behavior of `etag` to be similar to the Documents List API. And to help in determining which resource has newer information, add back the `app:edited` property as well (I think just documenting the value of `etag` is enough, like officially saying that the second part is an encoding of a timestamp, so that we can rely on it to be always increasing). Also, I think it's better to just change the `modifiedDate` property on content modification, and nothing else (e.g. not with ACL changes or description changes).

Similarly, `etag` of `Revision(List)` resources of verbatim files is not very useful as well. Since the `downloadUrl` property changes regularly, the `etag`s of each `Revision` and the whole list changes with it, rendering it useless (because you can't use it to check if the revisions didn't change). Good thing there is the `md5Checksum` property you can compare, but it's not reliable in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

Google's infrastructure updates Google docs asynchronously after updates. To my knowledge, this affects etag, thumbnails, and probably md5sum and certain modified dates.

Some documentation from Google confirming which items are asynchronous and which are synchronous would be tremendously useful to developers.

Comment: How did you discover this?  Was it just through experimenting with the API?  I would be interested to know if your comments are still true, 3 years later...

Comment: Experimentation. I doubt if it's changed since that would require a total redesign of the infrastructure. However the performance may be such that the delay is imperceptible.

Comment: Since Google Docs are collaborative, they run on a completely different system, similar to Google's now defunct Realtime API. In a collaborative setup, every individual change has to be stored, so what's actually "in" your Drive is a shortcut to a different set of processes somewhere in the heart of Google, and changes aren't immediately reflected in Drive.

Answer (score 0):

The etag is in effect, and often in practice, a hash of the file's metadata. If you change anything about a regular file (not a Doc or Sheet, see below), or just "touch" it using eg

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/blah_my_file_id/touch
```

the metadata is changed, and the etag you get back in the response WILL be different. My application, and likely thousands of others, utterly depend on this behavior. 
If you're seeing different, it's somewhere in your setup. Where the OP said "you can see that the ModifiedDate is earlier than ModifiedByMeDate"... er, it's not. It's identical in the JSON response they provided. The "LastViewedByMeDate" is different.

Google Docs, Sheets etc, are a completely different system since they are collaborative. Collaborative systems keep individual changes, and need very complex logic to keep it all straight; they're not just regular files. What's "in" your Drive is just a shortcut to processes running somewhere else in Google's caves, and the metadata you read from Drive may well be out of sync with recent changes. Google's now withdrawn collaborative Realtime API (which may still drive Docs and Sheets, I don't know) provided a serverRevision property which was the reliable way to track if any changes had occurred.